# Retrieve current userid from C# web services

Tags: web-services, c#-3.0, networkcredentials

I need to create a C# 3.0 Web service which is capable to retrieve (only) the userid of the CALLER in an intranet environment.  I realise I could possibly pass the information from the caller program but in my case it is not feasible.  The Web service is going to be consumed by a Windows app (Infopath 2003 to be precise)..and retrieve the userid from my Windows app is not practical in this circumstances.

Is that achievable?  The IIS (hosted in windows 2003 standard server) uses windows authentication.  I have tried a few things using WindowsIdentity but it only works for localhost.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "C# web service". Do you mean an ASMX service, or a WCF service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this? `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Thanks I will try that and report here for the result.

Comment: Hi I used that but it returns the (in)famous error message: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM’...

Comment: I have also tried Thread.CurrentPrincipal but it returns blank...sure I am missing something fundamental here...forgot to mention I am writing ASMX web service, not WCF

Comment: You stated above you are using windows auth, have you checked the IIS application to ensure that anonymous authentication is unchecked? The default is to have both anonymous and windows checked.

Comment: Well I thought the anon authentication had already been unchecked..but guess what?  So the problem was solved.  Thanks James